# Create Python WHL file only using bash

Tags: python-3.x, linux, bash, python-wheel, twine

I have access to a virtual machine with Python 3.11 and am able to create WHL files using the twine and build libraries.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install build
python -m pip install twine
python -m build
python -m twine upload dist/*
```

I would like to be able to build the wheel files on a Linux computer that only has access to Python 2.7.5.
Is it possible to accomplish this task using only bash commands?

Comment: I don't understand your question: Do you want to run a Python program written for Python 3 on a machine, where you want to have only Python 2.7? How is this related to bash?

Comment: I want to create a wheel file for a Python 3 script. The machine to distribute the code and package it only has Python 2 available.

Comment: How about installing Python 3? As long as you have a home directory on that machine, where you can put your own files, you can install whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a Python WHL file using bash involves a few steps. Here's how you can do it:

1. First, make sure you have a working Python environment installed on your system. You can check this by running the following command in the terminal:

```
python --version
```

This should output the version number of Python installed on your system.

2. Next, create a new directory where you'll be working on the package. For example:

```
mkdir mypackage
cd mypackage
```

3. Create a new Python module with your desired functionality. You can create a file called mypackage.py with the following content as an example:

```
    print("Hello, World!")
```

4. Create a setup.py file in the same directory with the following content:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='mypackage',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'mypackage = mypackage.mypackage:my_function'
        ]
    }
)
```

This file tells setuptools how to package and install your module. It also specifies that the mypackage command should run the my_function function from the mypackage.py module.

5. Install setuptools if you haven't already:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
```

6. Now, you can build your package by running the following command:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

This will create a WHL file in the dist directory with a name like mypackage-0.1-py3-none-any.whl.

That's it! You've created a Python WHL file using bash. You can now install it using pip:

```
pip install mypackage-0.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

And you can run the mypackage command to execute your my_function function.